# Poor graphics performance after installing proprietary driver nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a HP Elitebook 8760w and running Ubuntu 16.04

I would like to watch movies in HD, but when I select the latest Nvidia driver, the graphics are not smooth when I am in full screen mode. The overall performance of my laptop is poor with any Nvidia driver selected. I can only watch video with the nouveau driver, but that is not in HD

I have tried updating the drivers list and selecting the latest one. Didn´t work. I also tried bumblebee. But I am not sure if I have 2 graphic cards in my laptop. Bumblebee messed it up a lot more.

How can I optimise graphics on this machine?

Comment: It's really not a good idea to install something specific for hybrid graphics when one is not sure. HP Elitebook 8760w has no such thing. Instead it can have any of 3 Nvidia Quadro models or an AMD. Nvidia Quadro is notorious for being picky about the drivers version and Nvidia recommends 375 only: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114708/en-us (For reference only, do not install binaries from there)

Comment: Try `lspci | grep "VGA"` to find out what video chips the machine actually has.

Comment: Which player are you using to watch videos? Some support hardware acceleration, some don't. Also, when you are using the proprietary NVIDIA driver, could you verify that direct rendering is enabled? On a terminal, run: `glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I have an Gforce quadro 4000. I have tried the 375 driver, with the same result. I play video´s mostly online, through Netflix. But i test with youtube on firefox.

Comment: glxinfo lets me know that directrendering is enabled